# stacking multiple excel inputs using rbindlist and lapply

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I'm extremely new to R Shiny, so bear with me for a couple of moments here. I'm working on a Shiny app and one of the components I am trying to work out is to be able to upload multiple excel files and have them be appended/merged/stacked with each other. My current code is this:

```
shinyApp(
  ui = navbarPage("data upload",
                  fluidRow(
                    column(12,
                           sidebarPanel(
                             fileInput("file", "Upload data files:", multiple = TRUE)
                           )),

                    mainPanel(tabPanel("Data", dataTableOutput("data")),)
                  )),

  server = function(input, output) {
    readFile <- reactive({
      rbindlist(
        lapply(input$file$datapath, function (x)
          XLConnect::readWorksheetFromFile(
            x,
            sheet = 1,
            startRow = 8,
            endRow = -5,
            startCol = 0,
            endCol = 26,
            header = TRUE
          )),
        use.names = TRUE,
        fill = TRUE
      )
    })

    output$data <- renderDataTable(nrow((readFile())))
)
```

I'm not sure if I'm using the right functions or the right thought process. Thank you in advance for helping out!

Comment: Is something not working? (BTW: I've often found `XLConnect`'s reliance on `rJava` in a shiny environment to be a bit fragile, depending on the shiny server's configuration. A non-java solution should also work, either `readxl` or `openxlsx`. Just a suggestion.)

Comment: Another btw: `renderDataTable` is ambiguous, in that it can be `DT::renderDataTable` or `shiny::`. See the "Note" in https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.3.2/renderDataTable.html.

Comment: @r2evans The files I choose are getting read into the script and are shown in the data table, but they don't merge or stack together into one table, which is what I want to do.

Comment: If you insert `browser()` in that `readFile` reactive and run the `rbindlist(lapply(...))` manually, does it give the output you expect? Do they have the same column names?